# College Genetics: Xist vs. transposon

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, mutations

I'm taking introduction to genetics and I'm trying to understand the following question: Lets say there is a male cat with blue ears, a single gene mutation called BLU. 
We try to obtain pure bred blue-eared cats, mating the above cat we recieve: 
*Males with a different colored ears 
*Females with blue mosaic ears.

Now I'm trying to understand which is more likely. BLU being silenced by Xist or having non autonomous transposon on the BLU gene while only females have autonomous genes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think a transposon would cause this?